# Echo within a switch statement

Tags: php, xml

How can I achieve the following, I'm looking to echo out hard coded data within a switch statement:

```
<?php foreach ($xmlObject->fields[0]->field as $field) {
    switch((string) $field['name']) {
        echo "<td>" . $c . "</td>";
        echo "<td>1</td>";
        case 'published':
             echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";                          
             break;     
        case 'body':
            echo "<td>" . htmlentities($field->value) . "</td>";
            break;                           
        case 'title':
            echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
            break;                           
        case 'summary':
            echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
            break;                           
        echo "<td>publish</td>";
        echo "<td>closed</td>";                     
        echo "<td>closed</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        case 'title':
            echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
            break;                                              
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";                     
        case 'published':
             echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";                          
             break;
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>0</td>";                      
        echo "<td>http://www.domain.com/clients/ciw/?p=" . $c . "</td>";
        echo "<td>0</td>";
        echo "<td>policies</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>0</td>";

        //case 'parentId':
        //    echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
        //    break;

        //case 'SubjectArea':
        //     echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
        //   break;                          
    }
} ?>
```

I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting T_CASE or
>   T_DEFAULT or '}' in
>   /home/teamwork/public_html/clients/ciw/datatest/index.php on line 154

When changing the echo's to case it gets rid of the errors but doesn't output anything.

Comment: you cannot have echo without case in switch statement

Comment: @BhavikShah Would it be a case of putting all the echo's within the cases?

Comment: i have submitted an answer expressing my thoughts. Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cant have echo without case in switch statement, look at the code below variable $error will give output

```
switch(true)
{
    case (strlen($foo) > 30):
        $error = "The value provided is too long.";
    $valid = false;
    break;

    case (!preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i', $foo)):
        $error = "The value must be alphanumeric.";
    $valid = false;
    break;

    default:
    $valid = true;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some odd things going on there.

Firstly - you have two echos between your "switch" and your first "case".  This doesn't make sense.  if you want that to always be output, move it before your "swtich"

Secondly - you have echos after "break" and before the next "case".  This code will be unreachable.  Without putting a test case together I can't say for certain, but it may fail a syntax check too.

Thirdly - you seem to be treating "$field" inside your look as both an array (you reference $field['name']) and a class (you reference $field->value).  I suspect you're about to get some more problems once you fix your echo issue.  Trying to build a test case to prove the solution caused me a headache because of this, though that might just be because I don't know what's in xmlObject!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm not really sure what I'm doing with the switch statement, never used one before. This is the content I'm pulling in - http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/ciw/datatest/dbo_Content1.xml

Answer (score 0):

Just little modification in your switch case: Try this and check if it helps:

```
<?php
echo "<td>" . $c . "</td>";
echo "<td>1</td>";
foreach ($xmlObject->fields[0]->field as $field) {
    switch((string) $field['name']) {
    case 'published':
         echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";                          
         break;     
    case 'body':
        echo "<td>" . htmlentities($field->value) . "</td>";
        break;                           
    case 'title':
        echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
        break;                           
    case 'summary':
        echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";

        echo "<td>publish</td>";
        echo "<td>closed</td>";                     
        echo "<td>closed</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        break;
    case 'title':
        echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";                     
        break;
    case 'published':
         echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $field->value . "</td>";                          
         break;
    default:     //default case will be executed if none of the above case is satisfied
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>0</td>";                      
        echo "<td>http://www.domain.com/clients/ciw/?p=" . $c . "</td>";
        echo "<td>0</td>";
        echo "<td>policies</td>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td>0</td>";
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Refer [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for more details